# Update element within a cloned div

Tags: jquery

I have a div

```
<div id="myDiv"><h3 id="myHeader"></h3 ></div>
```

and I have created a few clones of that div

```
  var $divClone1 = $('#myDiv').clone();
  var $divClone2 = $('#myDiv').clone();
  var $divClone3 = $('#myDiv').clone();
```

I want to be able to set the value of **myHeader** to something different in each of the three clones - they idea would then to list all the individual clones to a screen with the different **myHeader** values.

How can this be achieved with jQuery?

Comment: be careful with using the same `id` for the cloned elements, it must be unique across your document. I would rather change them to something else every time you clone the object.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to introduce the most basic scenario in order to explain what I need.  Thanks for the heads up, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ids should be unique on a page. I'd suggest using class names instead of ids. If you need unique ids for each element, you could apply them AFTER the cloning.

I would use jQuery just once to get a reference to the original div, then make clones of that.

```
<div class="myDiv"><h3 class="myHeader"></h3 ></div> 

var $myDiv = $('.myDiv'),
    $divClone1 = $myDiv.clone(),
    $divClone2 = $myDiv.clone(),
    $divClone3 = $myDiv.clone();

$divClone1.find('.myHeader').attr('id', 'Clone1').text('Clone1');
// Attach to DOM
$divClone2.find('.myHeader').attr('id', 'Clone2').text('Clone2');
// Attach to DOM
$divClone3.find('.myHeader').attr('id', 'Clone3').text('Clone3');
// Attach to DOM
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if having multiple `ID`s of same value works here, but give it a try and remove the IDs too.

```
var $divClone1 = $('#myDiv').clone().removeAttr("id").find("h3").removeAttr("id").html("Hello");
var $divClone2 = $('#myDiv').clone().removeAttr("id").find("h3").removeAttr("id").html("World");
var $divClone3 = $('#myDiv').clone().removeAttr("id").find("h3").removeAttr("id").html("Senty");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not clone a tag that has IDs (or you should take care of them after cloning) because IDs are supposed to be unique. You should replace it by a class like this:

```
<div class="myDiv"><h3 class="myHeader"></h3 ></div>
```

Now you can use any $divCloneX and change any property like this:

```
$($divClone1).find(".myHeader").html("new value");
```

or

```
$(".myHeader", $divClone1).html("new value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply limit the `scope` and use `html()`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="myDiv"><h3 id="myHeader">foo</h3 ></div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $divClone1 = $('#myDiv').clone();
var $divClone2 = $('#myDiv').clone();
var $divClone3 = $('#myDiv').clone();

$('#myHeader', $divClone1).html('bar');
$('#wrapper').append($divClone1);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u285uz8z/)**